# send arguments on simulated click

Tags: jquery

How to send arguments on click?

```
// initiate the button
$('#btn').click(function(e){
    console.log(e.data);
});

// later on I need to simulate a click with parameter
$('#btn').click({
    param : 'simulated click'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass extra param to function handler using `trigger()` method:

```
// initiate the button
$('#btn').click(function(e, data){
    console.log(data);
});

// later on I need to simulate a click with parameter
$('#btn').trigger('click',{
    param : 'simulated click'
});
```

But if your goal is just to check if an event has been triggered programatically, you can check for:

```
// initiate the button
$('#btn').click(function(e){
    if(e.isTrigger) {
        console.log('simulated click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why cant we try using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) like this?

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){
    console.log($(this).data("param"));
});

$('#btn').data("param",{param : 'simulated click'}).click();
```

Comment: After a simulated click all mouse clicks will be simulated if you set `data` on the DOM element?

Comment: @clarkk I couldn't get you. what do you mean by all mouse clicks?

Comment: After you have done a simulated click on a specific element all clicks on the element afterwards will be simulated (the data-param will be sent)

Comment: Yeah.. of course it will be there for all the future clicks. If you don't want it, then just remove that data from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`$.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), like this:

```js
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
  console.log(e.param);
});

$('#btn').trigger({
  type: "click",
  param: "simulated click"
});
// => 'simulated click'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```